# "sur base de" ou "sur la base de"

Tags: grammaire, expressions, belgique

I work as a Flemish (Dutch speaking) employee in a Walloon firm in Belgium and I'm regularly trying to improve my knowledge of the French language.

In Dutch, the expression "On the basis of" ("Aan de hand van") is that common that there's an official abbreviation for it ("a.d.h.").
While looking for a French translation on Google, I found "Sur la base de". However, generally I hear the expression "Sur base de" (without "la").

Which one is correct?

Comment: Sur LA base de…

Comment: Can you provide us with examples of usage?

Comment: Linguee gives somewhat different translation for [*sur la base de*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/sur+la+base+de.html) and [*sur base de*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/sur+base+de.html) (See particularly the examples of usage below)

Answer (score 1):

*Sur base de* est [un belgicisme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sur_base_de).

Jamais entendu en France, ex aequo avec *essuie de bain* et [heure de table](https://jaimelesmots.com/lheure-de-table/). En revanche [carjacker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtNT_TNfs2U) a bien remonté.